# AWS EC2 folder access

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i have an AWS EC2 t2.micro instance that im doing some testing on.
Long story short, i have attached a SQLite DB to the .NET application that i have created, and im trying to insert data into the DB.

On my local it works 100%, but when i run it once its been published to my EC2 instance, i get an exception "attempt to write a readonly database".

After doing some research it states that it could be that the folder it is in is read only, after remoting into my EC2 instance, and checking the App_Data folder where the DB lies, the folder is Read-Only. But i cannot for the life of me un tick the Read-only box.

I would apply the change and then check again, and its back to being read only. Please could someone give me some guidance as to how i can make the folder writable.

Thanks!
George

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning off the SQLLite service first? Also you may need to add yourself (if you are an administrator) as an Owner of the directory before you can change the other permissions.

This should help:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753659(v=ws.11).aspx